# Why don't models connect to each other when sculpting?

Tags: sculpting

[image: screenshot 1]

*Hello everyone,* this is my first time working on a character model and I have a problem. I can't connect the arm manually. I don't know exactly why. I thought the problem was with the Voxel size, and I made the two models of equal value to be linked together. But I can't merge them together. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the sharpness in the models is lost and the fine details disappear.

What I want to tell here is that the arm and hand are connected to each other after using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> command, but this connection does not exist when I sculpt.

Voxel size 0.007m:
[image: screenshot 2]

I may not have explained myself fully, but I hope you understand my problem.
[image: screenshot 3]

What I want to do is do it like this:
[image: screenshot 4]

Thank you for your answers. <3

Comment: Hello, you need to either boolean or use the remesh tool, but remesh will change the topology...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am losing a lot when I remesh, but I have never tried the boolean option. Do you have any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: look into "Boolean modifier"

Comment: oh ok i got it i got what i mean. thank you so much :)  Sorry if I disrupted you